# python regex best way to extract image url

Tags: python, regex

How do I extract only the xlarge URL's from the below html with regex?

```
'"xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTU5WDEwMjY=/z/TQMAAOSwkrFaZqhh/$_20.PNG"},{"small":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_35.JPG","large":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_75.JPG","xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_20.JPG"},{"small":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_35.PNG","large":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_75.PNG","xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_20.PNG"}],"needsPhoneOnReply":false,
```

and these type of HTML

```
  <ul class="gallery__main-viewer-list">
                        <li class="gallery__main-viewer-item">
                                <span data-responsive-image="{
                                 maxWidth: 815,
                                 maxHeight: 600,
                                 small: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_20.JPG',
                                 medium: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_75.JPG',
                                 large: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_20.JPG' }" title="" class="gallery__img-wrap current" data-index="1"><img id="responsive-image-1535889965732" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_20.JPG" alt=""></span>
                            </li>
                        <li class="gallery__main-viewer-item">
                                <span data-responsive-image="{
                                    defer: 'true',
                                    small: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/gBgAAOSw8Ftbhugb/$_20.JPG',
                                    medium: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/gBgAAOSw8Ftbhugb/$_20.JPG',
                                    large: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/gBgAAOSw8Ftbhugb/$_20.JPG' }" title="Floor Mats For Toyota Corolla Zre152R/Zre153R (Sedans) May 2007 - Darra Brisbane South West image 2" class="gallery__img-wrap current" data-index="1">
                                    <noscript><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/gBgAAOSw8Ftbhugb/$_74.JPG" alt="Floor Mats For Toyota Corolla Zre152R/Zre153R (Sedans) May 2007 - Darra Brisbane South West image 2"></noscript>
                                    </span>
                            </li>
```

What is the best way to extract these xlarge urls? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to extract all xlarge urls using the regexp `r'"xlarge":"(.*?)"`

```
>>> re.findall(r'"xlarge":"(.*?)"', text)
['https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTU5WDEwMjY=/z/TQMAAOSwkrFaZqhh/$_20.PNG', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_20.JPG', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_20.PNG']
```

Comment: is it possible to do similar to this type of format?     small: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_20.JPG',
                                 medium: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_75.JPG',
                                 large: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDU2Mg==/z/H~QAAOSwpaZbhugU/$_20.JPG'

Comment: Yes. Just get rid of the double quotes from the pattern (`r'large: '(.*?)'`) and it would work fine for the string you have posted

Comment: It's empty for me re.findall(r'large:(.*?)', text) is this correct?

Comment: Try this `re.findall(r"large: '(.*?)'", s)`

Comment: Nope, still coming up as empty

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall` with zero-width positive lookbehind:

```
re.findall(r'(?<="xlarge":")[^"]+', str_)
```

- `(?<="xlarge":")` is a zero-width positive lookbehind pattern that matches `"xlarge":"` literally before the desired match which is one or more characters that are not `"` (`[^"]+`); in essence, `[^"]+` matches upto next `"`

Or with grouping:

```
re.findall(r'"xlarge":"([^"]+)', str_)
```

- Similar to above, but here, instead of lookbehind, we are putting `[^"]+` in a captured group and `re.findall` will output the groups only

**Example:**

```
In [1507]: str_  = '"xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTU5WDEwMjY=/z/TQMAAOSwkrFaZqhh/$_20.PNG"},{"small":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_35.JPG","large":"https://i.ebayim
      ...: g.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_75.JPG","xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_20.JPG"},{"small":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSw
      ...: p-RaZqhn/$_35.PNG","large":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_75.PNG","xlarge":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_20.PNG"}],"needsPhoneOnRe
      ...: ply":false,'

In [1508]: re.findall(r'(?<="xlarge":")[^"]+', str_)
Out[1508]: 
['https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTU5WDEwMjY=/z/TQMAAOSwkrFaZqhh/$_20.PNG',
 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_20.JPG',
 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_20.PNG']

In [1509]: re.findall(r'"xlarge":"([^"]+)', str_)
Out[1509]: 
['https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTU5WDEwMjY=/z/TQMAAOSwkrFaZqhh/$_20.PNG',
 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/uX0AAOSwvGlaZqhU/$_20.JPG',
 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjMwWDk2MA==/z/n58AAOSwp-RaZqhn/$_20.PNG']
```